# How to change MS-Chart area color in windows application

Tags: vb.net, windows, mschart

I am using MS-Chart in a **windows application**. How can I change the white area in the center of the chartarea?

[image]

Comment: use the `BackColor` property of `ChartArea` to change the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer to reflect comment:
Actual code using details from previous answers:
1st, dim and create (New) chart object (.Net chart rather than Excel chart).

2nd, Add a chart area and give it any name. The new ChartArea will have an index of 0.

3rd, Using the BackColor property, set the color to red.

```
dim MyChart as New System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
MyChart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea")
MyChart.ChartAreas(0).BackColor = Color.Red
```